# db2 - join each row to its prior row

Tags: db2

I have a table with many records, and a timestamp on each.  I want each record to join to the previous record's details.

Here's what I have tried:

```
Select t.*, max(timestamp) 
from TABLE as t
LEFT JOIN (
    Select * from TABLE 
) as prev_records on (prev_records.timestamp < t.timestamp)
```

This query tries to return a record, plus the record that was created just before it. I need to return the data from both records.  The approach I have tried is: for each row, I have to do a subselect in the select clause that selects the data where timeStamp = Max(timestamp)

As this:

```
Select t.*, max(timestamp) , ( Select id from TABLE  where timestamp = max(timestamp)) 
from TABLE as t       
LEFT JOIN (
    Select * from TABLE 
) as prev_records on (prev_records.timestamp < t.timestamp)
```

Is there any other solution to do this?

Comment: Your queries are syntactically incorrect and do not match your description. Anything you're not telling us? You should probably publish your table definition, some sample data, and the expected result. Don't forget to mention your DB2 version and platform.

Comment: Especially because some versions of DB2 have access to the `LAG(...)` window function, which would make this pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a common table expression, calculating ROW_NUMBER to rank the records by age, ie. backwards in time. Then you can connect each row to the next older one.

```
with INP as
( select t.*,
         row_number() over (order by t.whenAdded) as age
    from TABLE t
)
select c.variousFields, p.moreFields
  from INP c
  join INP p  on c.age=(p.age - 1)
```